# Prevent Angular web component from listening to keydown events outside of the shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, shadow-dom

I have a web component embedded on a page. I have a specific shortcut set, that listens for certain keystrokes. However, when I click outside of my web component, it still triggers the web component's listener.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
@HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const key = event.key.toUpperCase();

    if(key === "SPACE") {
        alert("Pressing space is not allowed");
    }
}
```

And here is what my HTML could look like:

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the front page</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />

    <p>Sign up to our newsletter:</p>
    <newsletter-signup></newsletter-signup> <!-- enter email, click button, etc. inside the component -->
</body>
```

When I press <kbd>space</kbd> inside the component, it will alert saying not allowed. Great.

However, when I press <kbd>space</kbd> in the search input on the page, it will also trigger. Even when I just click space/kbd> after reloading the page, it will still trigger it.

How do I prevent this from happening outside of my component? BEAR IN MIND that the `HostListener` should listen for keydown events on the ENTIRE component. That means I cannot simply limit the listener to specific input elements.

My component is using shadow DOM:

```
@Component({
    ...,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

Comment: The way you put it > `document:keydown`, it will listen for any keydown event in the entire document, no matter if it's in your component or not. As long as the component is in the dom, it will listen for that keydown event. Also keep in  mind that any elements inside of your component still technically are... in your component, thus it will trigger the listener..

Comment: @MikeS. Yes, I am aware of that. I want this to listen to ANY keydown inside my component. However, not outside of it. On the outside, I don't want it to listen when I try to search, for example.

Comment: remove the `document:` from your HostListener and see if that works. If it doesn't, a stackblitz reproduction of the problem would be helpful to iron out the issue.

Comment: @MikeS. I'll try that tomorrow and create a Stackblitz if I fail. Web components in Stackblitz is quite annoying to create, but I'll manage

Comment: Looking at the [`HostListener` docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) you should be using a `Directive` to limit the scope. So something like `<newsletter-signup keyup>`

Answer (score -1):

With your listener on `document` you can't *prevent* the trigger of an event.

Inside your event handler you can check where the Event came from and *ignore* it.

Using:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode

Comment: That is not the case. When I check the path (even when text has been selected in my component), it's still only body -> document -> window (or something like that).

Comment: Forget StackBlitz; use [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/) it has NG9 scaffolding. If a component triggers an event, composedPath should have the full path. Or is it a "closed" component?

Comment: That's a pretty nice website to be honest. Thanks for the share